# How to get all the h4 elements

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Trying to get all the h4 elements. I can see some when I look at the HTML: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbmrB.jpg

This code doesn't get any.

```
page = requests.get("https://www.larosas.com/menu/default.aspx")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
h4 = soup.findAll("h4")
print(h4)
```

It prints

[]

Comment: that's because you don't have any <h4> tag in the content of the page (I don't see any inside the source code neither inside the chrome console)

Comment: there are no h4 tags

Comment: I am confused because I see some here: https://imgur.com/a/pAFr5Sq

Comment: When you access the default.aspx URL for the first time or in incognito/private browsing, the landing page indeed has no h4 tags ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KLtF.jpg)). This is the same page accessed by `requests`. But when you navigate to the same page you are saying that has h4 tags (the one with the "Starters and Wings"), it indeed has h4 tags ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNKtK.jpg)). The problem is both have the same URLs, and your current code is getting the page without h4 tags.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you check the page redirection and final source code what you are getting.

After typing the above URL its redirecting to this URL
https://www.larosas.com/menu/larosas-menu.aspx
and there are no H4 tags present there.